# Сравнение двух рекурсий

Tags: java, рекурсия

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть две рекурсивные функции.
Первая

```
     public class MyClass {
    int recursionFunc1(int tmp0, int tmp1, int tmp2) {
        return recursionFunc1(tmp0, tmp1, tmp2);
    }
}
```

Вторая

```
 public class MyClass {
    int recursionFunc2(int tmp0, int tmp1, int tmp2) {
        int a = tmp0 + tmp1;
        int b = tmp1 + tmp2;
        int c = tmp2 + tmp0;
        return recursionFunc2(a, b, c);
    } 
}
```

Скажите, как можно определить какая из этих рекурсий раньше упадет по StackOverflowError ? Задание это аналитическое.

Comment: Что-то не очень похоже на рекурсию. Даже если бы это она и была, упадут обе одинаково.

Comment: @Mage нет, не одинаково, т.к. локальные переменные выделяются на стеке.

Comment: @Drylozav ну так и проанализируйте. Какова глубина рекурсии? Что еще попадает на стек? Вас же не соцопрос пропросили провести.

Comment: @a_gura если данный код будет опитимизирован в процессе компиляции, то не будут

Comment: @Mage Что значит если? Рекурсия здесь (ну будм считать что она есть) хвостовая. Но Java-компилятор не оптимизирует хвостовую рекурсию.

Comment: @a_gura так и не надо :), я же не про оптимизацию рекурсии

Comment: @Mage А про что вы? Про inline результатов сложения в вызов метода? Так их все-равно надо положить на стек. А ну да, тогда объем данных на стеке будет такой же :)

Comment: задание и состоит в том , что бы предположить , какая из этих рекурсий упадет раньше по StackOverflowError ?

Comment: Оптимизирующий компилятор _имеет право_ заинлайнить рекурсию, увидеть, что переменные не используются, и выкинуть их. В С++ пустой бесконечный цикл в точности является [UB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5905171/276994), насчёт Java не уверен.

В любом случае, вопрос не имеет смысла в отрыве от специфики системы, поскольку стек является лишь _деталью конкретной имплементации_.

Answer (score 4):

Экспериментальным путем установлено, что все-таки вторая рекурсия упадет раньше, значит ничего не оптимизируется и [[@a_gura](/users/1439/a_gura)](/users/1439/a_gura) изначально дал правильный ответ. Оба класса запускались на выполнение с параметром -Xss1M. В результате: для первого 8507 вызовов, для второго - 7005

```
public class MyClass1 {
    int count = 0;

    int fun(int tmp0, int tmp1, int tmp2) {
        count++;
        return fun(tmp0, tmp1, tmp2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass1 m = new MyClass1();
        try {
            m.fun(0,0,0);
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println(m.count);
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass2 {
    int count = 0;

    int fun(int tmp0, int tmp1, int tmp2) {
        count++;
        int a = tmp0 + tmp1;
        int b = tmp1 + tmp2;
        int c = tmp2 + tmp0;
        return fun(tmp0, tmp1, tmp2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass2 m = new MyClass2();
        try {
            m.fun(1,2,3);
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println(m.count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а почему ? можете объяснить поподробнее

Comment: Вам знакомо понятие стэка процесса? ассемблер может быть чуток знаете/помните?

Comment: @Drylozav Вы не предполагать должны, а именно анализировать. Для анализа вам нужно знать ответы на вопросы, которые я вам задал в комментариях к вопросу. Вы не можете вечно ходить на форумы за ответами. Включайте голову. Погуглите про выделение памяти в Java, про стек, и т.п.

Comment: Интересно вообще в рамках какого предмета (курса и т.п.) задают такие вопросы, что за ответом надо обращаться к общественности

Comment: Я не знал где искать . Я спрашиваю на форуме , т.к. хотел получить ответы , но если это запрещено, то ладно.

Comment: «Экспериментальным путём установлено» означает «установлено для данной версии данного компилятора и рантайма с данными настройками оптимизации». С другой версией оптимизатор может оказаться и умнее.

Comment: @VladD для джавы такой подход вряд ли работает, естественно проверял на том что есть - JDK1.7

Comment: @Drylozav если вам не рассказывали как устроен вызов функций на низком уровне, то объяснение этого займет слишком много времени

Comment: @Drylozav не запрещено задавать вопросы. Но не поощряется отсутствие мысли и желание получить ответы без предварительно проведенной работы. В комментариях есть много подсказок. Дерзайте.

Comment: Я объясню почему спрашиваю . Я читаю про рекурсию . потом смотрю задания после этой темы и там есть этот вопрос . Я знаю что можно измерить глубину рекурсии с помощью счетчика и потом просто их сравнить, но когда нужно было сравнить их аналитически, то мне было не понятно изначально как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вызов функции помещается в стек, локальные переменные также в стеке. Стало быть упадет раньше тот рекурсивный метод у которого в стеке больше переменных. В данном случае количество аргументов одинаково, различаются только локальные переменные. Стало быть упадет раньше второй способ.

Comment: Исследование заказано группой британских учёных?